# Govendor tool takes a lot of time to fetch a single dependency

Tags: go, govendor

I'm new using Golang and on many projects I was giving a look there is a *vendor* directory which turns out to be a valid Go directory structure for projects dependencies; by checking some Github projects I noticed a vendor.json inside this vendor directory, so investigating a bit it turns out that json file is generated by *govendor* tool.

So in order to learn how to use this tool for dependencies I first initialized using:

```
$ govendor init #which created vendor/ and vendor/vendor.json
```

My problem comes when installing a dependency using *govendor fetch*, it takes about 10min to fetch just a single dependency.

```
$ govendor fetch github.com/hashicorp/consul
```

Is that a normal behavior when adding a new dependency or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 10 min looks really long, but know that that package looks kinda big, contains other vendored packages, and also imports other packages which need to be fetched recursively. Pass `-v` to see what it does under the hood.

Comment: Yeah, Consul is a massive dependency with many cascading dependencies, and isn't really intended to be brought in at its root (the root is its main package, which cannot be imported). Libraries which are intended to be imported generally don't have their own vendor directory as this leads to various problems. The root as you've imported it even includes consul's web UI and the entire consul.io website.

Comment: Thank you guys, you are right, it was because of the size of consul I was trying to read. Indeed I was missing one /api at the end that's why it was downloading everything. The verbose -v option helped me a lot to figure it out.